# http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback 404 error

Tags: reactjs, express, proxy, micro-frontend

I am trying to get my backend development server and my microfrontend development servers working nicely together. The challenge for me is that the frontend is a microfrontend, and in my case it's two separate development frontend servers that need to connect to one backend development server.

The backend has a Google OAuth flow via localhost:5000/auth/google.

So I need implement a sign in with Google on the `auth/` sub app of my mfe.

So if this were a monolithic frontend it would be straightforward to me in that I would just install `http-proxy-middleware` on the **client** side, or at least that's how it's done these days.

However, working with a microfrontend, my thinking is, this library would just need to be installed in the `auth/` sub app of my mfe where the authentication work is being done.

However, it is my understanding that CRA looks for the `setupProxy.js` file that I would have to create after installing that library, but my microfrontend was not created with CRA, so would that mean that I need to create a proxy the old-fashioned way?

By going into my `package.json` file inside my `auth/` sub app and writing in like so:

```
"proxy": {
   "/auth/google": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
   }
}
```

I ask because when I tried to click on this link:

```
export default function SignIn({ onSignIn }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Container component='main' maxWidth='xs'>
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component='h1' variant='h5'>
          Do not provide your credentials. You can simply click the Sign in
          button to see our future dashboard
          <hr />
          <a href='http://localhost:5000/auth/google'>Sign In With Google</a>
        </Typography>
        <form
          onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
          className={classes.form}
          noValidate
        >
```

just testing it of course, this is not the final product, I get the following error in console:

> GET
> http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback?code=4%2F0AY0e-g5D_VhmwLDSBaLdmlZ10BJQljRL3P0C28fIaQE8NqbQqgRiF-INflN3zEYFmpHFTw&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&authuser=0&prompt=none
> 404 (Not Found)

I did not get a **redirect_uri_mismatch** in the browser, instead I got:

```
Cannot GET /auth/google/callback
```

Comment: Is your client being loaded from http://localhost:5000/?

Comment: @BipilRaut, no, the client is a microfrontend being loaded from localhost:8080, this is the container parent app where the auth/ sub app is being rendered through. Its in that sub app that I added the proxy logic.